# How format date input for credit card, expiry date?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date, credit-card

I'm trying to format the input date for my credit card into my HTML, and I tried use brmasker for mask but both sides go 99/99(mm/yy), and the pattern does not work with ionic I guess.

```
[brmasker]="{mask:'00/00', len:5}"
```

Actually I do not what I can use for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: not solved my problem

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is then...

Comment: Is this question tagged properly? Are Angular and Typescript a part of what you are trying to fix, or should it be tagged with brmasker and ionic?

Comment: My problem is that i can modify a specific input in my input lol, like mm/yyyy. I do not know how do that, i was thinking in use pipes maybe...

Comment: @ecg8 i said brmasked because i was using him for other inputs

Comment: Have you looked at ion-datetime? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime/

Comment: If you are using Angular, you can make use of `pipes`. https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: @StephenRomero Yes, but was not what i wanted, I need a input for user do manually